# Streamlit redirect user to URL without interaction for auth

Tags: oauth-2.0, streamlit, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to authenticate users of my streamlit app using OAuth 2 as described in [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-google-oauth-in-streamlit-bb7c3be0082c) (article repo [here](https://github.com/uiucanh/streamlit-google-oauth) if you can't access post). That implementation provides users a link to click that initiates the OAuth flow and records the access token within the streamlit session. However, if the user refreshes the page the session is lost and the user needs to click a link again to go through the OAuth flow again.

I'm wondering if there's a way to handle the OAuth flow in a way that's more transparent to the user. Is there any way to kick off authentication without user interaction (eg. issue a redirect to the auth URL if the session doesn't have a valid token) within Streamlit?